# No-copy cache line aligned function storage object with small object optimization

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I have implemented a `std::function`-like class,

- that is optimized for storing lambdas,
- that never copies the stored function,
- that has a small buffer to store small functors, avoiding dynamic memory allocation.
- is designed to be sized to exact multiples of a cache line, because the functors will probably be accessed from different cores.
- stores the size of the stored object to be able to decide whether to treat it as a small-object or large-object.
- allows one storage container to store a lot of different types of callable objects

Also,

- Objects that are too big automatically fall back to a `new`, and only a pointer is stored.
- Bare function pointers are supported, stored in the small object buffer
- It does not use vtbl for `operator()` codepath. Calls are resolved at compile time.
- It generates a helper function that "knows how" to move and dispose of the object. A pointer to that template function is stored with the object.
- The "dispose" function for small objects explicitly calls the destructor on the object in the small object buffer. The dispose for large objects uses `delete` to be symmetrical with large object `new`.

To use it you make a map or deque to construct in place or move construct into place. You can then use the `R v = it->invoke<R, T, A1, A2...>(A1, A2...)` to execute `R T::operator()(A1,A2...)` on the stored instance.

Note that it actually allows a lot of different types of lambdas to be stored in the same container (`deque`/`map`/etc), so it is not directly comparable with `std::function`.

Questions:

- Am I missing anything important? What won't work? Is there any Undefined Behaviour?

---

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdint>
#include <set>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

// totalSize is the size of the entire object, not the payload
// the actual payload size is less than that by sizeof pointer
template<std::size_t totalSize = 128>
class CallableStorage
{
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t smallSize = totalSize -
            sizeof(std::size_t(*)(void*));

    using Storage =
            typename std::aligned_storage<smallSize>::type;

    template<typename T>
    CallableStorage(T&& fn)
        : CallableStorage(typename std::integral_constant<
                         bool, sizeof(T) <= smallSize>::type(),
                         std::move(fn))
    {
    }

    CallableStorage(CallableStorage const&) = delete;
    CallableStorage& operator=(CallableStorage const&) = delete;

    CallableStorage(CallableStorage&& r)
        : size(r.size)
        , helper(r.helper)
    {
        MovePair places;
        if (size <= smallSize)
        {
            places.from = &r;
            places.to = this;
            r.helper(HelperCommand::Move, &places);
        }
        else
        {
            payload.largeStorage = r.payload.largeStorage;
            r.payload.largeStorage = nullptr;
        }
    }

    CallableStorage& operator=(CallableStorage&&) = delete;

    ~CallableStorage()
    {
        if (size <= smallSize)
            helper(HelperCommand::Dispose, &payload.smallStorage);
        else
            helper(HelperCommand::Dispose, payload.largeStorage);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* lambdaPointer()
    {
        return lambdaPointer<T>(
                    typename std::integral_constant<
                    bool, sizeof(T) <= smallSize>::type());
    }

    template<typename T>
    T const* lambdaPointer() const
    {
        return lambdaPointer<T>(
                    typename std::integral_constant<
                    bool, sizeof(T) <= smallSize>::type());
    }

    template<typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
    R invoke(Args&& ...args)
    {
        return invoke<R, T, Args...>(
                    typename std::integral_constant<
                    bool, sizeof(T) <= smallSize>::type(),
                    std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    enum class HelperCommand
    {
        Dispose,    // pointer to object
        Move        // pointer to MovePair
    };

    struct MovePair
    {
        void* to;
        void* from;
    };

    template<typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
    R invoke(std::true_type, Args&& ...args)
    {
        auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&payload.smallStorage);
        return ptr->operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template<typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
    R invoke(std::false_type, Args&& ...args)
    {
        auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(payload.largeStorage);
        return ptr->operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template<typename T>
    CallableStorage(std::true_type, T&& fn)
        : size(sizeof(T))
        , helper(lambdaHelper<T>)
    {
        new (&payload.smallStorage) T(std::move(fn));
    }

    template<typename T>
    CallableStorage(std::false_type, T&& fn)
        : size(sizeof(T))
        , helper(lambdaHelper<T>)
    {
        payload.largeStorage = new T(std::move(fn));
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* lambdaPointer(std::true_type)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&payload.smallStorage);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T const* lambdaPointer(std::true_type) const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T const*>(&payload.smallStorage);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* lambdaPointer(std::false_type)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(payload.largeStorage);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T const* lambdaPointer(std::false_type) const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T const*>(payload.largeStorage);
    }

    template<typename T>
    static std::size_t lambdaHelper(HelperCommand cmd, void* p)
    {
        if (p)
        {
            using IsSmall = typename std::integral_constant<bool,
                sizeof(T) <= smallSize>::type;

            switch (cmd)
            {
            case HelperCommand::Dispose:
                lambdaDisposerImpl<T>(IsSmall(), p);
                break;

            case HelperCommand::Move:
                auto const& move = *reinterpret_cast<MovePair const*>(p);
                lambdaMoveImpl<T>(IsSmall(), move);
                break;
            }

        }

        return sizeof(T);
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void lambdaDisposerImpl(std::true_type, void* p)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)->~T();
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void lambdaDisposerImpl(std::false_type, void* p)
    {
        delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(p);
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void lambdaMoveImpl(std::true_type, MovePair const& p)
    {
        CallableStorage& lhs = *reinterpret_cast<CallableStorage*>(p.to);
        CallableStorage& rhs = *reinterpret_cast<CallableStorage*>(p.from);

        T* from = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&rhs.payload.smallStorage);
        T* to = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&lhs.payload.smallStorage);

        new (to) T(std::move(*from));
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void lambdaMoveImpl(std::false_type, MovePair const& )
    {
    }

    union Payload
    {
        Storage smallStorage;
        void* largeStorage;
    };

    Payload payload;
    std::size_t size;
    std::size_t (*helper)(HelperCommand, void*);
};
```

Comment: From a quick look at your code, I can't see the use of all those headers. Do you really need them all?

Comment: @user2296177 You are correct. I'll put this thing in its own file and minimize the includes.

Answer (score 2):

## Don't cast forwarding references to rvalue type

Here, we use `std::move()` on a type that could be an lvalue reference:

```
template<typename T>
CallableStorage(T&& fn)
    : CallableStorage(typename std::integral_constant<
                      bool, sizeof(T) <= smallSize>::type(),
                      std::move(fn))
{
}
```

We must use `std::forward<T>` instead, and/or constrain `T` to be an rvalue reference type:

```
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value,
                  "CallableStorage requires a moveable argument");
```

## Is it useful to store functions with different signatures?

We've lost a lot of the convenience of `operator()`, as we now have to specify template arguments to `invoke()`.  I think it would be better to have the function signature as part of the type, unless there's a demonstrated need for heterogeneous function storage.  At present, it seems like we're pushing too much knowledge onto the user.

## Size calculation is wrong

It looks like we've omitted the `size` member when computing the size for `Storage`.  It should be

```
static constexpr std::size_t smallSize =
    totalSize - sizeof (helper_type) - sizeof (std::size_t);
```

(I shuffled things around in my copy to give `helper` a named type; I think that's worthwhile, to reduce accidents)

Just a note about terminology in the comment - `sizeof pointer` is ambiguous here, because *function* pointers are not necessarily the same size as *object* pointers in C++.

## Unnecessary headers

We're including way too many Standard Library headers (but still omitting one we do need, for `std::aligned_storage`).  I believe these are what's required:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
```